# How to read first and last column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I looking for solution but can't find anything working.

So I have a txt file. It's looks like this:

```
geneName1, sampleName1, Allel, allel2, 055, 33, tumor
geneName2, sampleName1, Allel, allel2, 321, 1, ntn
geneName3, sampleName1, Allel, allel2, 32, 44, ddd
geneName4, sampleName1, Allel, allel2, 123, 2, aga2
geneName1, sampleName2, Allel, allel2, 01255, 23, tumorD
geneName2, sampleName2, Allel, allel2, 33, 1, ad2
geneName1, sampleName3, Allel, allel2, yyu
geneName2, sampleName3, Allel, allel2, hhf
geneName4, sampleName3, Allel, allel2, vgv
geneName5, sampleName3, Allel, allel2, aga5
```

And it's don't have a header. But for clear:

```
nameOfGene, sampleNumber, Allel1, Allel2, GS1, GS2, descr
```

Do as u can see some lines has not `GS1`, `GS2` data, but all have a `descr`.
All what I need is `[nameOfGene,sampleNumber,Allel1,Allel2,descr]`

And that's the problem. I tried many solution from internet but can't solve it.

I tried to modify `usecols=[]` parameter in `pd.read_csv` to `usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,:-1]`, but pandas don't understand something like that and I got olny syntax error.
I tried read whole df but then `desc` is readed as `GS1` (if `GS1` is not in line).

I tried `concat`, but result is the same like above, and when line don't have GS1 the desc is loaded as GS1, and next to cols are 0 or NaN.

Maybe I just ommit something and exist good solution to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your text file is named `myfile.txt`

```py
import pandas as pd

my_file = open("myfile.txt")
text = [k.split()[0:4]+[k.split()[-1]] for k in my_file.readlines()]
my_file.close()
df= pd.DataFrame(text)
# next line is optional, just if you want named columns
df.columns = ['nameOfGene','sampleNumber','Allel1','Allel2','descr']
print(df)

   nameOfGene  sampleNumber  Allel1   Allel2   descr
0  geneName1,  sampleName1,  Allel,  allel2,   tumor
1  geneName2,  sampleName1,  Allel,  allel2,     ntn
2  geneName3,  sampleName1,  Allel,  allel2,     ddd
3  geneName4,  sampleName1,  Allel,  allel2,    aga2
4  geneName1,  sampleName2,  Allel,  allel2,  tumorD
5  geneName2,  sampleName2,  Allel,  allel2,     ad2
6  geneName1,  sampleName3,  Allel,  allel2,     yyu
7  geneName2,  sampleName3,  Allel,  allel2,     hhf
8  geneName4,  sampleName3,  Allel,  allel2,     vgv
9  geneName5,  sampleName3,  Allel,  allel2,    aga5
```

Comment: Thank u very much! It's works almost perfect. It's generate whole line as one string, but I can handle with it. U helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

First read in just the first row as a datframe. Then, read in two separate dataframes with the required columns with the second datframe syntax being `[-2:-1]` to read the last column. Then merge the datframes together on index:

```
cols = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1).columns
df1 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=cols[0:3])
df2 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=cols[-2:-1])
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
df
```

Comment: Actually, @Gillu13 's solution is probably the best one here. Didn't realize the differences in rows. Essentially, the rows have different numbers of columns. I will leave my solution up in case it is helpful though. I focused on the solution to the `usecols` workaround rather than looking at the actual data. There isn't anything you can really do with `usecols` here as even if you read in the last column, there would be blank/null values for the rows that have less columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to edit your file to include values that are not available in GS1 and GS2. Might work by adding 2 commas before *descr*.
After you import it as a dataframe in pandas, use the code

```
new_df = dataframe[['nameOfGene','sampleNumber','Allel1','Allel2','descr']]
```

This will store the new dataframe containing only nameOfGene, sampleNumber, Allel1, Allel2, descr columns.
If you want only the first and last columns exclude sampleNumber, Allel1 and Allel2.

Comment: Although, that would work, it doesn't answer the OP's question. What if the OP is reading in a MASSIVE .txt file and is running into memory limitations on his/her computer? Then, the OP would need a more robust solution that only reads the desired columns.

Comment: @DavidErickson Yes that sounds about right. I missed that. Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 1):

The below code takes your text file and creates a new column containing descr information.
We then remove unnecessary columns from this dataframe to leave you with only what you want to keep.

```
import pandas as pd

file='*.txt' ##put your file path and filename here
DATA = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header=None)

new_data=[]
#print(DATA)
#print(len(DATA))
for i in range(len(DATA)):
    #print(DATA.loc[i][6])
    if not DATA.isnull().loc[i,6]: 
        new_data.append(DATA.loc[i][6])
    else:
        new_data.append(DATA.loc[i][4])
DATA['NewColumn'] = new_data
DATA=DATA.drop(DATA.columns[[4,5,6]], axis=1)
print(DATA)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. You can try the following, being careful about how you read the data, and then putting everything together into the desired Dataframe.

```
columns = ['nameOfGene', 'sampleNumber', 'Allel1', 'Allel2', 'descr']
file = open('test_data.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
for line in lines:
     split_line = line.split(',')
     if len(split_line) == 7:
           row_data = split_line[0:4] + [split_line[6]]
     elif len(split_line) == 5:
           row_data = split_line

     row = pd.Series(row_data, index=columns)
     df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
   nameOfGene  sampleNumber  Allel1  Allel2      descr
0  geneName1   sampleName1   Allel   allel2      tumor
1  geneName2   sampleName1   Allel   allel2      ntn
2  geneName3   sampleName1   Allel   allel2      ddd
3  geneName4   sampleName1   Allel   allel2      aga2
4  geneName1   sampleName2   Allel   allel2      tumorD
5  geneName2   sampleName2   Allel   allel2      ad2
6  geneName1   sampleName3   Allel   allel2      yyu
7  geneName2   sampleName3   Allel   allel2      hhf
8  geneName4   sampleName3   Allel   allel2      vgv
9  geneName5   sampleName3   Allel   allel2      aga5
```